# difference between mAdded & mActive in source code of support.FragmentManager

Tags: android, fragment

Recently I'm reading the source code of `FragmentActivity`(sorry that I can't find the source in github, I'm using a native source jar file). The `FragmentManager` contains the following two members:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> mAdded; //
ArrayList<Fragment> mActive; //
```

What's the difference of the two? and in what cases a `Fragment` will be in `mAdded` while not in `mActive`?

Answer (score 7):

**mAdded:**

- Contains fragments that have been added and not removed or detached from the activity.
- These fragments are **privileged** in the sense that they can:

  - Respond to events such as:

    - low memory events
    - configuration changes
  - Display custom menus and respond to menu item selections.

**mActive:**

- A superset of `mAdded` that includes all fragments referenced by any `FragmentTransaction` objects in the backstack.
- Fragments that are **NOT** in `mAdded` will not be able to respond to events or display custom menus.

**What events modify these two fragment lists?**

- **mAdded**

  - a fragment is **added** to this list if the fragment is added to the activity.
  - a fragment is **removed** from this list if:

    - the fragment is removed from the activity.
    - the fragment is detached from the activity.
- **mActive**

  - a fragment is **added** to this list if the fragment is added to the activity.
  - a fragment is **removed** from this list **ONLY** under the following two scenarios:

    - it has been removed from the activity and is NOT in the backstack.
    - a transaction is popped off the backstack and either an add or replace operation is reversed on a fragment that is now no longer referenced by the backstack.

**Conclusion**

`mAdded` is a list of fragments that the are **alive** in a sense, while the `mActive` list is a complete list of all fragments that are still tied to the activity.  `mActive` contains all **living** fragments (`mAdded`) and **freeze dried** fragments (sitting on the backstack waiting to be resuscitated via `backStackRecord.popFromBackStack()`.

Continuing with the analogy of living and cryogenically preserved entities: as activities execute callbacks like `onConfigurationChanged()` or `onLowMemory()`, the only fragments that really care about being passed the opportunity to respond to these events are the live ones.

So you'll see in `FragmentManagerImpl` that the callback is only looking at the `mAdded` or **living** fragments.

`fragmentManager.dispatchLowMemory()` is called by `activity.onLowMemory()`.

```java
public void dispatchLowMemory() {
    if (mAdded != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<mAdded.size(); i++) {
            Fragment f = mAdded.get(i);
            if (f != null) {
                f.performLowMemory();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a good discussion about these two lists here: https://github.com/kgleong/software-engineering/wiki/Fragment-Manager#madded-and-mactive-fragment-lists

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but I found some clues about mActive and mAdded.

I found this in the source code of FragmentManager:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean moveToStateNow) {
    if (mAdded == null) {
        mAdded = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "add: " + fragment);
    makeActive(fragment);
    if (!fragment.mDetached) {
        if (mAdded.contains(fragment)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already added: " + fragment);
        }
        mAdded.add(fragment);
        fragment.mAdded = true;
        fragment.mRemoving = false;
        if (fragment.mHasMenu && fragment.mMenuVisible) {
            mNeedMenuInvalidate = true;
        }
        if (moveToStateNow) {
            moveToState(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

The point is around the fifth line we call **makeActive(fragment);**.

This method calls **mActive.add(fragment)** so

- mActive is incremented each time you call fragmentManager.addFragment()
- mAdded is incremented when you call fragmentManager.addFragment() **AND** when (!fragment.mDetached) is true (look the code above)

So my guess is mAdded contains only the fragments which are attached to the activity and mActive contains the initialized fragments. 
But I didn't look deep enough to be sure of my statement ...

I hope this helps